# Use aggregate to facilitate calculations

Tags: r, aggregate, large-data

So recently I've been learning the functions of aggregate and I find it really useful for large data sets I work with. Normally I manually manipulate data in excel which, while effective, is extremely time consuming.

So I was wondering if the following could be done. I have a data set that is similarly structured like so (but much bigger):

```
Fruit    Crate   Mass
Apple    A       4
Banana   A       3.4
Orange   B       2
Apple    C       2.1
Apple    C       4.5
Banana   C       5
Orange   D       1
Apple    D       1.3
Orange   D       2.4
Orange   D       3.2
Orange   E       2
Banana   E       1.1
Banana   E       0.7
Apple    E       2
```

Now I know with this I get Mass per crate:

`TotalCrate<-aggregate(data$Mass,list(crate=data$Crate), sum)`

And with this I get Mass per fruit per crate:

`FruitperCrate<-aggregate(data$Mass, list(fruit=data$Fruit, crate=data$Crate), sum)`

Now is there a way that I can get percent mass of fruit per crate, so basically, is there a way that I can divide the fruit mass by the total mass of for each respective crate? And if so, how can I do it for future reference.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What about `FruitperCrate$PercentMassOfFruitPerCrate <- FruitperCrate$x/TotalCrate[FruitperCrate$crate,"x"]`?

Comment: Please provide inputs in reproducible form.  See [mcve].  In this case I have done it for you in the Note at the end  of my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** First aggregate by `Fruit` and `Crate` and then use `ave` with `prop.table` to get the proportions of each fruit in its crate:

```
ag <- aggregate(Mass ~ Fruit + Crate, data, sum)
tr <- transform(ag, percent = 100 * ave(Mass, Crate, FUN = prop.table))
```

giving:

```
> tr
    Fruit Crate Mass   percent
1   Apple     A  4.0  54.05405
2  Banana     A  3.4  45.94595
3  Orange     B  2.0 100.00000
4   Apple     C  6.6  56.89655
5  Banana     C  5.0  43.10345
6   Apple     D  1.3  16.45570
7  Orange     D  6.6  83.54430
8   Apple     E  2.0  34.48276
9  Banana     E  1.8  31.03448
10 Orange     E  2.0  34.48276
```

or graphically:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(tr, aes(Crate, percent, fill = Fruit)) + 
   geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
   scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "yellow", "orange"))
```

[image: screenshot]

**1a)** This could also be expressed in a magrittr pipeline like this:

```
library(magrittr)
data %>%
     do(aggregate(Mass ~ Fruit + Crate, ., sum)) %>%
     transform(percent = 100 * ave(Mass, Crate, FUN = prop.table))
```

**2)** and here is an alternative using dplyr that follows similar logic:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
   group_by(Crate, Fruit) %>%
   summarize(Mass = sum(Mass)) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   group_by(Crate) %>%
   mutate(percent = 100 * prop.table(Mass)) %>%
   ungroup()
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
    Crate  Fruit  Mass   percent
   <fctr> <fctr> <dbl>     <dbl>
1       A  Apple   4.0  54.05405
2       A Banana   3.4  45.94595
3       B Orange   2.0 100.00000
4       C  Apple   6.6  56.89655
5       C Banana   5.0  43.10345
6       D  Apple   1.3  16.45570
7       D Orange   6.6  83.54430
8       E  Apple   2.0  34.48276
9       E Banana   1.8  31.03448
10      E Orange   2.0  34.48276
```

**3)** A 2d layout could be had using `xtabs`:

```
xt <- 100 * prop.table(xtabs(Mass ~ Crate + Fruit, data), 1)
```

giving:

```
> xt
     Fruit
Crate     Apple    Banana    Orange
    A  54.05405  45.94595   0.00000
    B   0.00000   0.00000 100.00000
    C  56.89655  43.10345   0.00000
    D  16.45570   0.00000  83.54430
    E  34.48276  31.03448  34.48276
```

which can be readily be shown in a graph like this:

```
plot(xt, col = c("red", "yellow", "orange"), 
     main = "Proportion of Mass of Fruit per Crates")
```

giving:

[image: screenshot]

The 2d layout can be reformed into long form with `ftable`:

```
ftable(xt, row.vars = 1:2)
```

giving:

```
Crate Fruit            
A     Apple    54.05405
      Banana   45.94595
      Orange    0.00000
B     Apple     0.00000
      Banana    0.00000
      Orange  100.00000
C     Apple    56.89655
      Banana   43.10345
      Orange    0.00000
D     Apple    16.45570
      Banana    0.00000
      Orange   83.54430
E     Apple    34.48276
      Banana   31.03448
      Orange   34.48276
```

**Note 1:** The two lines of code in the question could be written using formula notation like this:

```
aggregate(Mass ~ Crate, data, sum)

aggregate(Mass ~ Fruit + Crate, data, sum)
```

**Note 2:** The input used in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "Fruit    Crate   Mass
Apple    A       4
Banana   A       3.4
Orange   B       2
Apple    C       2.1
Apple    C       4.5
Banana   C       5
Orange   D       1
Apple    D       1.3
Orange   D       2.4
Orange   D       3.2
Orange   E       2
Banana   E       1.1
Banana   E       0.7
Apple    E       2"
data <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for you, using `data.table`, although there are certainly other ways:

```
library( data.table )
setDT( data )
data[ , mass := sum( mass ), by = .( crate, fruit ) ]
data <- unique( data )
data[ , total.mass.crate := sum( mass ), by = crate ]
data[ , percentage.mass.crate := ( mass / total.mass.crate ) * 100 ]
```

So we're first aggregating the mass for each fruit within each crate (since I notice that some fruits are listed more than once in a single crate) to get the total mass for that fruit in the crate. Then we're adding a column to show the total mass of each crate, showing the value on every row. Then, by dividing the mass of each fruit by the total mass for that crate, we get the percentage of mass for each fruit in the crate.